# PHP losing session after a form POST? Jquery File Upload

Tags: php, forms, session, jquery-file-upload

I have a form which calls a page `upload.php`:

```
<form action="http//path/to/upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This page is using blueimp's [JQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin which returns a JSON response with the data of the files being uploaded.

Problem is, for the internal working of my site, I absolutely need the file uploader to store some information in the session.
But if I call `upload.php` page directly, `session_start()` works... when called by the form the session is lost and a new one is being created, making it impossible to share the needed information between pages.
Any suggestions or hints?

EDIT: obviously, the page with the form has its own, working, session. Problem is that the id are different and the session of `upload.php` is empty. But not if I call upload.php *directly*, in which case the correct session is retrieved!

Comment: check the session cookie's save path on both the "expected" and the "new" sessions. if they differ, you'll have to fix the path setting so the same cookie can apply to both requests.

Comment: you have `http//path/to/upload.php` is this another site? Try making the link relative

Comment: @MarcB: using session_save_path() in PHP yields "/tmp" in both cases.

Comment: @Waygood: the link is absolute but in the same domain. Does this matter perhaps?

Comment: @cranio: I mean the cookie path on the client-side.

Comment: @MarcB: excuse me for the n00b-ish question, how do I retrieve the cookie path on the client-side? (can I use Chrome's developer utilities?)

Comment: absolute can be `/path/script.php` without the domain

Comment: i think the session is regenerated what framework are u using

Comment: @DeepakSrinivasan: I don't think so, because if I call the page individually (NOT with the form but *directly*) the session just works fine: id's are the same. ONLY using the form (which doesn't make a refresh, but returns JSON data) the session is not retained but created again.
Btw, the framework is an obscure, very poorly written framework I have to mantain and expand.

Comment: can't u post the data along with form as hidden element?

Comment: @cranio: use a debugger, like firefox's firebug, or the ie/chrome developer tools. you can check out everything to do with cookies using those.

Answer (score 0):

In the page with the form that calls `upload.php`,add `session_start()` as the first line. Rename it to `.php` if it is not already.

Comment: session_start() is present, working and on the first line (it's a framework). But the session_id's are different, upload creates a new one.

Comment: hmm, check the `session_progress.*` value in php.ini..sometimes it messes session up if it is enabled..

Comment: alas, I have no access to the php.ini on the server.